# What is T in EitherT?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, monad-transformers

Reading about EitherT [here](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/eithert.html).

Any idea what T in EitherT represents?

Comment: Transformer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_transformer